# Replacing ${} with maven profile

Tags: xml, spring, maven

Im trying to set a property with a maven profile. I need to change the resource location with a maven profile, but im getting a recurrent error, idk what its wrong.

Target (src/main/resources/context/mvc.xml):

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/photos/*" location="${file.mapping}"></mvc:resources>
```

Profile:

```
<profile>
        <id>windows</id>
        <activation>
            <os>
                <family>Windows</family>
            </os>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <file.mapping>file:///C:/software/photos/</file.mapping>
        </properties>
        <build>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </build>
</profile>
```

Error:

```
Could not resolve placeholder 'file.mapping' in value "${file.mapping}"
```

Comment: What maven command are you using?  It's possible the windows family maven profile activation isn't working.  Running the command "mvn enforcer:display-info" helps determine what OS "family" maven compares to.

Comment: I had a wrong family, maven compare it with "dos". But the error continue. I also tried to force the profile execution, but same results.

Comment: Someone found the answer for my $ problem, with my spring version i need to use @variable@. But you was right with the family problem and your command help me a lot. Thank you very much bro.